# Нахождение всех источников конфигурации во время загрузки Spring

Tags: spring

Делю Spring-приложение на джарники, хочется запихнуть всю конфигурационную инфраструктуру в один джарник. Получается примерно такая ситуация:

```
backend-base.jar -> backend-auth-service.jar
backend-base.jar -> backend-file-service.jar
```

Внутри backend-base.jar находится `@Configuration`-класс, который конфигурирует `o.s.c.s.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`, которому, в свою очередь, и надо проставить значения по умолчанию (которые разделены на backend-base.jar и зависящий от первого jar). Как это правильно сделать? Можно ли каким-то образом объявить интерфейс и найти все его реализации в текущем пакете, чтобы с его помощью объявлять классы значений по умолчанию?

Есть вариант со сканированием пакета, но, конечно, исходный джарник не должен знать о зависимых от него.

Answer (score 1):

В результате все оказалось реализовано следующим образом:

Я выкинул предлагаемый спрингом способ конфигурации, несмотря на то, что у него есть ряд преимуществ. Вместо этого я создал простой класс `Settings`, являющийся оберткой над простым `HashMap<String, Object>`:

```
public class Settings {
    public boolean exists(String key) { ... }
    public Object get(String key) { ... }
    public void set(String key, Object value) { ... }
}
```

класс ApplicationSettings, который является агрегатором настроек и еще одной оберткой `HashMap`:

```
public class ApplicationSettings {
    public boolean exists(String key) { ... }
    public Object get(String key) { ... }
    public <T> T get(String key, Class<T> targetType) { ... }
    public void set(String key, Object value) { ... }
    public void setAll(Settings settings) { ... }
}
```

интерфейс SettingsProvider:

```
public interface SettingsProvider {
    Settings getSettings();
}
```

и аннотацию `@DefaultSettingsProvider`, по которой и находятся источники данных по умолчанию:

```
public @interface DefaultSettingsProvider {
    // а ничего тут и нет
}
```

После этого я создал еще один класс ApplicationSettingsFactory, который занимается тремя вещами:

1. Находит все аннотированные @DefaultSettingsProvider реализации SettingsProvider и поочередно запихивает лежащие внутри них данные в ApplicationSettings (для поиска используется класс спринга с адовым названием [ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.html) и рутовый пакет приложения, в котором находятся все остальные классы)
2. Находит все файлы конфигурации (application.properties, application.local.properties, application.%profile%.properties, application.%profile%.local.properties) и так же поочередно складирует их в тот же экземпляр ApplicationSettings
3. Запускает два пост-процессора, которые поочередно ищут переопределения тех или иных настроек в `-D`-свойствах и, наконец, в переменных окружения.

Из плюсов этого подхода:

- Удалось реализовать желаемую иерархию настроек, благодаря чему приложение и запускается на дев-машине с просто "ожидаемыми настройками", и легко конфигурируется в докер-контейнере с помощью обычных переменных окружения (12-factor app остался доволен).
- При правильной работе можно создавать свои бины не с фиксированными настрйоками, а подтягивающими их каждый раз (или раз в N времени) из ApplicationSettings. Это позволяет менять настройки на лету и вводить, например, новые ноды для репликации, чего спринг из коробки позволить бы не смог.
- Получилось реализовать няшную консольную команду `settings`, которая выводит все настройки приложения и облегчает дебаг.
- Ключ настройки задается константой, которая потом переиспользуется в @DefaultSettingsProvider, что исключает возможность ошибиться.

  ```
  @Configuration
  public class RedissonConfiguration {
      public final static String REDIS_URI_SETTINGS_KEY = "service.redis.uri";

      public Redisson redisson(ApplicationSettings settings) {
          String redsUriRepresentation = settings.get(REDS_URI_SETTINGS_KEY, String.class);
          ...
      }
  }

  @DefaultSettingsProvider
  public RedissonDefaultSettingsProvider implements SettingsProvider {

       public static final String REDIS_URI = "redis://localhost:6379";

       public Settings getSettings() {
           Settings settings = new Settings;
           settings.set(RedissonConfiguration.REDIS_URI_SETTINGS_KEY, REDIS_URI);
           return settings;
       }
  }
  ```

  Спринг использует SpEL, который мне не нужен, но который по очевидным причинам требует оборачивать имена настроек в @Value с помощью `${}`, что для меня оверкилл.
- Благодаря тому, что в концепции спринга это просто созадваемый бин, при иницализации нет проблем в недоступности каких-либо низкоуровневых сервисов приложения, инициализации статических полей и т.п.

Из минусов:

- Все-таки не удалось избежать скана всего пакета приложения целиком.
- В случае, если у меня есть подключаемая по-требованию конфигурация (например, Redis, который нужен не во всех дочерних микросервисах), то @DefaultSettingsProvider все равно подтянет значения из него. В будущем, возможно, я просто создам аннотацию для конфигурации, указвающую, где для нее лежат настройки по умолчанию.